# Populate EditText with value from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

In my Android application I have a TextView with an EditText. I want to prepopulate the EditText with the last value entered, which is stored in the SQLite database?

Comment: What have you done so far?  The values already stored in the sqllite database or you want to store it now?

Answer (score 5):

This should not be so hard I think:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
    String value = // Query your 'last value'.
    editText.setText(value);
}
```

If you want to learn more about SQLite database storage, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) article in Android document.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an edittext to it's resource ID via `getViewById(R.id.xxxx)`

then do a SQLite query for the highest PID...

then pull theString you're looking for out of the result cursor...

assign that via
editTextId.setText(theString);

be sure to enclose it in a try/catch and assign the edittext to some arbitrary default value if the db exec fails due to no entries in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this By using `Spinner` inside `EditText`.

Take `EditText` and `Spinner` inside a `RelativeLayout` retrieve data from DB and assign those values to the spinner.

By using `OnItemSelectedListener` to the spinner u can assign the selected values to ur `EdiText`.