# Populate data in EditText boxes

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sqlite

Is there is any possible way to populate my `EditText` boxes with the data that is saved in `SQLite` database. I search, try to learn and understand from many websites that how to get data that is already inserted in `SQLite` database and I can retrieve it from any activity and populate in required `EditText`. Please help how to insert data in `SQLite` and how to read and populate in `EditText` boxes. I will be thankful to you. Can anyone guide me that i got an error **"MySQL is not responding or not getting data"** when I establish connection to `PHP` and Android and get data from `MySQL`. How can I resolve this problem

Comment: Perhaps by posting some code for what you are trying to do within your Android application we can better help you.

Comment: Please review the edited answer. I display my code there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check these..
[fetching data from database and set it on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630859/fetching-data-from-database-and-set-it-on-edittext)
[Populate EditText with value from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921386/populate-edittext-with-value-from-database)
[How to store the data from edittext to android sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793795/how-to-store-the-data-from-edittext-to-android-sqlite-database)
Also a tutorial over database operation..
http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/working-with-sqlite-on-android/